# How to display div under button if this one is clicked? Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to show a `div` under a `button` when this one is clicked

I'm working in Angular 2 I would like to use functions like `*ngIf` and `(click)` but I don't know where to start doing that.

Inside my button I have `(click)="show=!show"` and inside my hidden div, I have `<div *ngIf="show">{{baseColor.name}}</div>`.

In my `export class{}` function I have `show = false;`

EDIT:

Best way

I have already my `selected` method `[ngClass]="{'selected': baseColor.state.selected}`so I have put inside my div `*ngIf="baseColor.state.selected"`

So now I have `<div *ngIf="baseColor.state.selected">{{baseColor.name}}</div>` without any extra code.

Comment: Can you share the entire relevant code?

Comment: Your approach seems legit. What exactly is the issue then?

Comment: thanks all guys, I was looking for a way to do it better.

Comment: IMO, nothing wrong with your approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Component.ts

```
is_show = false;
toggleDiv() {
    this.is_show = !this.is_show;
}
```

In Html

```
<button (click)="toggleDiv()">Show / Hide</button>
<div *ngIf="is_show"></div>
```

Comment: many thanks, it is right but I was looking a better way to do it. thanks anyway

Comment: Sure, You can also use like this . <button (click)="is_show = !is_show">Show / Hide</button>
<div *ngIf="is_show"></div>